# How to increase the output range of a current source?

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, current-source, dac

I'm trying to design a current source to charge a capacitor (10pF) in the context of IC, with quite a small voltage headroom (1.5V). I started with the basic current mirror, as shown below. M3 acts like a switch, controlling when to start/stop charging.

This works fine when the voltage on the capacitor (call it Vcap) is not too high, because as Vcap rises, Vsd of M2 decrease, and M2 gradually enters triode region, sourcing less current than IREF.

Now I'd like to make IREF adjustable. Ideally to adjust it from 1uA to 10uA (quite a large range). I tried by directly changing the value of IREF, but the error becomes very large.

I'm wondering if there are any methods for designing a current source/current mirror/DAC that can achieve this output dynamic range (and have a large output impedance at the same time)?

[image]

Comment: M3 is a bit of a hindrance possibly so, how good is it if M3 is bypassed (just to establish a potentially better method).

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, why is M3 the hindrance here? I don't quite get it.

Comment: It may not be but, it's worth 10 seconds simulating without it surely.

Comment: M3 will increase the output resistance but will reduce the compliance depending on the bias applied to M3 gate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching off capacitor-charging current by opening the current mirror leg is not a good solution, considering that the CM frequency response might be poor and you might want the charging current to be precise at any moment of time. So, you better use current steering to have a copy of charging current from your current mirror and then control your charging current from outside your precise current mirror (Iload is a network with Vcap; while switching off charging, you can also disconnect the M3/M5 gates).

[image: basic current steering circuit]

As for current mirror designs aimed at achieving a large IREF range, enhanced output impedance, and high output swing, the recommendation may depend on your project goals and technology used. General ideas are like this: use cascode architecture to increase the output impedance or maybe introduce source degeneration via ohmic MOS transistors.

An idiomatic low-voltage cascode current mirror solution looks like this:

[image: wide swing current mirror]

Biasing the CM with Ibias minimizes the systematic error of current copying; the closer Vbias to the M5 drain voltage, the more accurate is the equality of Iref and Iload, but the exact equality Vbias = V(M5d) disables the cascode, and it is the designer job to find optimum.